# can't remove Ext.data.Store records using Cell Editing Plugin

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

Hi i've been getting this error message for a while now and i'd like to know what am i missing. Thanks in advance.

This is the model:

```
 Ext.define('Recepcion',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                {name: 'obra_social_id', type: 'string'},
                (... etc)
            ]
        });
```

This is the Store:

```
//the first line is the array supposed to contain the data?
```

var datosPlanillaRecepcion= [];

```
var storePlanillaRecepcion = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Recepcion',
    data: datosPlanillaRecepcion,
    proxy: { type: 'memory'},
    autoSync:true
});
```

And finally the grid bound to the store

```
planillaRecepcionGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

        id:'gridRecepcion',
        store: storePlanillaRecepcion,
        flex:0.7,
        height:600,
        autoScroll:true,
        selType: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: [cellEditing],
        columns: [
            columnaOS = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                text     : 'Obra Social',
                flex     : 0.5,
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'obra_social',
                renderer: function(value){
                    //return pasarMayusculas(value);
                    return value;
                },
                editor: {
                    allowblank: false
                    //clicksToEdit : 1
                }
            }),
            columnaTotal = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
                text     : 'Total',
                flex     : 0.2,
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'obra_social_recepcion_cantidad_total',
                value    : ' ',
                editor: {
                    type:'numberfield',
                    allowblank: false,
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 1000000
                },
                renderer: function(value){
                    if (value==0)
                        return '';
                    else
                        return value;
                },
                listeners:{
                    validateedit: function(){

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }),

            (...)

            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 50,
                items: [{
                    tooltip: 'remove',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                        grid.getStore().remove(rec);

                    }
                }]
            }],

        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: false,
            border: 25,
            markDirty:false,
            listeners: listenersGridRecepciones
        }


    });
```

as you see i use the Cell Editing Plug-in to fill the grid with data.
I do this by programatically adding rows to the grid this way

grid.getStore().add({});

adding emtpy objects and the editing them with the mentioned plug in

the thing is that when i click on the action column it throws me the

'o is undefined' error and a line number pointing to the following function

```
getKey : function(o){
   return o.id;
},
```

wich by the way belongs to Ext.util.AbstractMixedCollection

what can it be?, i know! "is a pain in the ass" question but perhaps i'm missing something really simple

Thanks!

Comment: what's the call stack? Which line in the code you provided calls that "getKey" function?

Comment: That is your empty record, define the idProperty in your model and then add with that, like this:
`grid.getStore().add({id:xxx});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**how to fix**

```
This is a bug, just place the null check by replace code in MixedCollection

getKey : function(o){
if(o)
return o.id;
else
return null;
}

thanks,
Kamal A. Siddiqui
Sr. Software Engineer (ACIT)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `add` method to work on your store, you must specify a default value for each field as defined in your `Model`.

For example...

```
grid.getStore().add(
 { obra_social_id: 'id', anotherField: 'fieldVal' ... }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

there was no solution, it was a bug that made me loose lots of days
in version 4.0.1 it was fixed

[EXTJSIV-1762] - Grid: CellEditing problems destroying